# Hibernate Save Entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp

I have 2 Entities, Vehicle & Driver. A Vehicle has a Driver. In the Vehicle class generated by Hibernate, this notation is represented by...

```
public class Vehicle
{
    private Driver driver;
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

In DB the following is the scenario...

```
table vehicle
    id INT
    name VARCHAR(20)
    driverId INT

table driver
    id INT
    name VARCHAR(45)
```

I am creating a Vehicle and want to assign a existing Driver. Using Hibernate, when I create a Vehicle object and save it, I have to do the following...

```
// Load Driver
Driver driver = (Driver) session.load(Driver.class, Integer.parseInt(iKnowTheDriverId));

// Create Vehicle
Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
v.setDriver(driver);
```

Do I need to load the corresponding Driver entity everytime or is there anyway to just set the Driver ID?

Thanks in advance...

SG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the corresponding `Driver` when saving a new `Vehicle`.

```
// Load Driver
Driver driver = (Driver) session.load(Driver.class, driverId);

// Create Vehicle
Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
v.setDriver(driver);
v.setName("someName");

session.save(vehicle);
```

But using `session.load()` to get the corresponding `Driver` is a good choice to avoid an `SQL SELECT` to the database. The `driver` object will not be fully initialized until you read a property on it. Only then the `SQL SELECT` is issued.

Comment: This may also lead to EntityNotFound? But this is exactly what I want to avoid. In SQL, I would just update the Driver ID in the table column. I want a similar way here...

Comment: "This may also lead to EntityNotFound?" No. If you know the id of the driver hibernate will always return the reference. I assume that the driver is already saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Driver temp = new Driver();
temp.setId(iKnowTheDriverId);

v.setDriver(temp);

session.merge(v);
```

It might be some differences between the save-methods, but if you use Session#merge() it should work. It will then merge the detached driver with an existing by checking their id, and null values in the detached object won't overwrite not-null values in the persisted state. Just make sure you have a CascadeType.MERGE/ALL on your reference from Vehicle to Driver.

Comment: In what way did it not work? Do you have CascadeType.MERGE on you association from Vehicle to Driver?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(userDetails);
        Long userId = userDetails.getId();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        logger.info("Successfully added the user");
        return userId;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("error in saving the user in user table", e);
    }
```